# How to regex everything that is enclosed between two certain strings in visual selection

Tags: regular-expression

I want to find the string enclosed by string1 and string2 and replace it with something else. I got a few lines that look something like

```
some_string_and_string1_some_rndom_string_string2_and_more
sme_string_and_string1_some_random_string_string2_and_more
some_string_and_string1_some_random_string_string2_and_mre
...
```

I thought the regex to match everything enclosed by string1 and string2 is

```
/^string1.*string2$
```

So the regex would match

```
string1_some_rndom_string_string2
string1_some_random_string_string2
string1_some_random_string_string2
...
```

But if I select the lines and try

```
:'<,'>s/^string1.*string2$
```

I get

```
Pattern not found: ^string1.*string2$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `^` and `$`. `^` is `start of a line` - which means that expression you're looking for needs to be at the very beginning of a line.
The same goes for `$`, which means `end of a line`. In you're case there is something between `^` and `string1`/`$` and `string2`, and regex expects that `string1` will be first, and it finds `some_string_and_` instead.

```
string1.*string2
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look at is if you have `set nomagic` in your `.vimrc`.

See `help magic`:

```
Examples:
after:    \v       \m       \M       \V         matches
                'magic' 'nomagic'
          $        $        $        \$         matches end-of-line
          .        .        \.       \.         matches any character
          *        *        \*       \*         any number of the previous atom
```

You can temporarily change it with `\m` (or `\v`):

```
:'<,'>s/\mstring1.*string2
```

or use

```
:'<,'>s/string1\.\*string2
```